# SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-membership

I was working with the new version of ASP.NET MVC3 and examining the WebSecurity class.  I've added System.Web.Webpages as a reference and am able to the use the WebSecurity properties and methods however i'm trying to understand how to configure it inside an ASP.NET page and not one built by WebMatrix.  In the Webconfig file, I did notice in the AppSettings section, a new key called enableSimpleMembership with the value set to 'false'.  Changing that to 'true' seemed trivial however they must have a SimpleMembershipProvider in the membership\providers section of the Webconfig file.  Has anyone seen that or attempted to incorporate SimpleMembership inside an ASP.NET page and does anyone know about adding a SimpleMembershipProvider to the webconfig file?  I have referenced [this](http://blog.osbornm.com/archive/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages.aspx) but it didn't seem to have all the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to simply set enableSimpleMembership="true" in appSettings and then remove any reference to a default membership provider such as AspNetSqlMembershipProvider (it will get registered for you).

Just confirmed that it works with an MV3 RC project.

Comment: This solved it for me! Adding: `<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />` into the `web.config`

Answer (score 4):

I created a NuGet package to enable SimpleMembership in ASP.NET MVC3: http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SimpleMembership.Mvc3

This should automate all the steps.

Enjoy!

Adam